# How to send characeters to the print command and have them printed in one line?

Tags: android, thermal-printer

```
public void printText(String text, int fontsize, boolean doubleW, boolean bold, boolean center) {

    if (this.mPrinterModule != null) {

        byte [] alignment = alignRight();
        byte [] alignment = alignCenter();
        byte [] line_space = setLineSpacing(10);
        byte [] font_size  = fontSizeSetBig(fontsize);
        byte [] left_margin = setLeftMargin(24,0);

        this.mPrinterModule.sendData(left_margin);
        this.mPrinterModule.sendData(font_type);
        this.mPrinterModule.sendData(line_space);
        this.mPrinterModule.sendData(font_size);
        this.mPrinterModule.sendData(alignment);

        PrinterModule printerModule = this.mPrinterModule;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append(text);
        stringBuilder.append("\r\n");
        printerModule.sendMessage(stringBuilder.toString(), "GBK");
    }
}
```

This is a print method I use to get text printed using my thermal printer. Instead of text I want to send character by character with their own individual style format. All the characters should be printed in one line as well. Any help will be greatly appreciated.Thank you in advance

```
public void sendMessage(String message, String charset) { 

    super.sendMessage(message, charset); 

    if (checkUsbPermission()) { 

        if (this.mConnected) { 

            this.mUsbCtrl.sendMsg(message, charset, this.mDevice); 

        } else { 

            this.mCallback.onError(ErrorCode.DEVICE_NOT_CONNECTED); 

        } 

    } 

} 



public synchronized void sendMsg(String msg, String charset, UsbDevice dev) { 

    if (msg.length() != 0) { 

        byte[] send; 

        try { 

            send = msg.getBytes(charset); 

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) { 

            send = msg.getBytes(); 

        } 

        sendByte(send, dev); 

        sendByte(new byte[]{(byte) 13, (byte) 10, (byte) 0}, dev); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: it is hard without knowing which printer and printer sdk you are using. edit your question with specific printer version and sdk to make your question clear.

Comment: Also, show the actual and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the time, the method `sendMessage()` of the PrinterModule has methods of  `print` and `moveToNextLine` implemented within it. Hence, the character is printed and cursor moves to next line immediately after you call the `sendMessage()` method.

You will have to make changes in the `sendMessage()` method implementation of the PrinterModule. Remove the `print` and `newLine` calls from  `sendMessage()` method. Then you can send as many characters as you want in `outputStream`. When you want to finally print, just send the `print` command to the Printer.

> UPDATE

The `sendMessage()` method calls `sendMsg()` which ultimately execute the statement `sendByte(new byte[]{(byte) 13, (byte) 10, (byte) 0}, dev);` . This line is responsible for printing after every `sendMsg()` call. This `byteArray` contains command for printing and adding newLine everytime some message is sent to it. Remove this line from here.

After that keeping sending characters to printer using `sendMessage()`. When you finally want to print the whole statement, then only send the command `PrinterModule.sendByte(new byte[]{(byte) 13, (byte) 10, (byte) 0}, dev);`. All your characters would be printed in one line if there is enough space, otherwise it be moved to next line.

> UPDATE 2

Here is the link for the [UsbController](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14KdhP2M22tCzMDoy-wNv6KGB83FnRokr/view?usp=sharing). You can directly add this as a new file in your project(no need to add the SDK files). The way to use the `UsbController` class is here in [UsbFragment](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Mxv4pmonWSTS1VszhFSfULDKbh9I_C-u/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Is it possible to write a new method instead of editing sendMessage() method. If so could you please provide a code snippet

Comment: The sendMessage() method doesnt have a print newline . How do I edit it? Please help

Comment: Sure i will help.Provide the code snippet of `sendMessage()` .

Comment: I edited my original question and added the sendMessage() methods there. Could you kindly look in to it ?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Also i have checked the same on my printer. Its working as expected. If you have any difficulty, feel free to ask, as i have implemented the same on my side.

Comment: This sendMessage() method is a module in the printer lib. How can I access the source codes of these modules. I have imported them at the beginning . But I dont know how I can edit them in Android Studio. Thank You so much for all the help provided so far

Comment: You can just copy the PrinterModule code and paste it in a new file in your own code. In that way you will have full access to all the functions. Also you can modify them according to your will.

Comment: How did you test it at your end without the lib file? Maybe I can use that method in my program, if you can kindly share. Sorry for the delayed reply

Comment: I have library file of my own printer. All these libraries are more or less same. They do the same task of connecting to printer and then sending data to the printer. So, i was able to test it on my side.

Comment: Well i can share the file, but where?.

Comment: Can you upload the file here https://uploadfiles.io/ and send the link. Thank you.

Comment: Okay sure, I will do. By the way, you can accept/upvote the answer so that it can be of help to others.

Comment: Hi, i have updated the answer. You can find the links for the text files. Look for the `sendMsg()` method, also i have added comments in the `USBController` file. If this doesn't work, you can share your printer SDK jar file, i will provide the editable file to you.

Comment: Thank you so much for assisting me . It works perfectly.